# collation change after server downgrade

Tags: sql, sql-server

My DBA team has changed the version of SQL server from standard to developer yesterday for the development environment.
After that we encountered some collation mismatch inside stored proc, the procedures were running fine till yesterday but from today onwards we are getting collation mismatch error. 
When i checked on test server the same procedures are running fine and the collation on both dev and test server are same that is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Now i need to prove them that this happend after server downgrade and i do not know much about collation.

What should i check and send them that can save our day.

Comment: Collation can be defined at multiple levels and preference goes like this: table level > database level > server level. Your best bet is to check collation for the column throwing error in both the environments.

Comment: That's an **upgrade** not a downgrade. Developer is equivalent to Enteprise. As for the collation, why do you care? Do you use ASCII (varchar) instead of Unicode fields (nvarchar)? That's a bug in the database design. Change your `varchar` fields to `nvarchar`.

Comment: What is the server collation of the development server now? SKU upgrades *shouldn't* change the collation anyway. Did the DBA *uninstall* the previous version? What SQL Server version was it? 2014, 2016, 2017?

Comment: If the collations on dev and test are the same check for bugs in the stored procedures and your tables, not the server. Perhaps you changed the *column* or *database* collations. What are the *specific* errors? What do the stored procedures do?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you please run this on both: test and dev environments: 
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));

Comment: both are giving Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: But i am getting collation error on one server only.

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: Then my answer is for sure irrelevant, removing it,

Comment: It can be that your original dev server had  collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and DBAs set it to "Latin1_General_CI_AS" during edition downgrade to make it aligned to TEST. But there are still objects in old dev that using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, so combining of collations gives you such errors